# Can I set sender's address in TJvMail

Tags: delphi

I use TJvMail to send emails with Delphi and it works fine but I would like to use a different sender's address than the default one in the email client.
In email client there are more than one sender addresses and I know which one  can use.
How I Can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TJvMail is a wrapper for Simple MAPI. As such, the sender address is whichever address is assigned to the MAPI account you login with to send the email, as specified by the `ProfileName` property. So, you cannot change the sender address.

If you want to customize the sender name or address, you will have to stop using MAPI and use SMTP directly instead.